# How to sort an object by value but still have access to the keys of the object in a mapping function?

Tags: javascript, object

Basically I have an object that looks like this.

```
 var obj = {cat: "Cat",
 dog: "Dog",
 long: "Long",
 modified_r: "Date Last",}
 mal: "Mal"}`
```

What I want to do is map over the object and sort it by value but still have access to the keys of the object.

What I have at the moment is

```
let sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort().map((value) => {
    return {value: value[0], label: value[1]}
});
```

This sorts the object by its Keys and then returns an array of objects like so.

```
0: {label: "cat", value: "Cat"}
1: {label: "dog", value: "Dog"}
2: {label: "long", value: "Long"}
3: {label: "mal", value: "Mal"}
4: {label: "modified_r", value: "Date Last"}
```

What I want to do is return an array of objects sorted in alphabetical order by its value like this.

```
 0: {label: "cat", value: "Cat"}
 1: {label: "modified_r", value: "Date Last"}
 2: {label: "dog", value: "Dog"}
 3: {label: "long", value: "Long"}
 4: {label: "mal", value: "Mal"}
```

I have tried to map the object using `Object.values(selectOptions).sort().map((value) => {}`. 
This sorts the objects by its values like how I want however I don't have access to the objects keys in this mapping function so I can't return the array of objects in the format that I want it.

What is the best way to map through an object sorting it by its values while still having access to the objects keys?

Comment: Below this comment: "What I want to do is return an array of objects sorted in alphabetical order by its value like this."  They appear to be sorted by _label_ not by _value_.  So which did you mean?

Comment: use a `for...in` loop on the object

Comment: @Wyck That was actually a mix up. I updated the question there to have {label : "cat", value: "Cat"} rather than {value :"cat", label: ""Cat}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": "value3",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value1"
}

let sortedByKey = Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1).map((value) => {
    return {label: value[0], value: value[1]}
});

let sortedByValue = Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => (a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 1).map((value) => {
    return {label: value[0], value: value[1]}
});

console.log(sortedByKey);
console.log(sortedByValue);
```

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation of how this sort function works? What is 'a', 'b' in this context? And what does the -1 : 1 condition mean?

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort ... basically 'a' and 'b' are any 2 items in the array and the function returns either '1' to change the order of the 2 given items or '-1' to leave them in their positions

Comment: FYI: `compare = (a,b) => (b<a)-(a<b)` is the JavaScript pattern for a three-way comparison predicate, which will appropriately return -1, 1 and 0 for equality too.  Then you would use `.sort((a,b) => compare(a[0], b[0]))` And probably define `by = key => (a,b) => compare(a[key], b[key])` so you can write `.sort(by(entryIndex))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator in the sort function to sort by value.

```
let sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => {
  return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
}).map((value) => {
    return {value: value[0], label: value[1]}
});
```